# Showing that $\cosh \pi z$ is of moderate decrease

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f(z)= 1/\cosh \pi z$. I would like to show that there exists a constant $A>0$ such that 
$$|f(x+iy)| \le \frac{A}{1+x^2} \; \text{for all} \; x\in \mathbb{R} \; \text{and} \; |y|<a$$ for any $|a| < \frac{1}{2}$.

To show this, I have first written $\cosh \pi z = e^{\pi z} \frac{1+e^{-2\pi z}}{2}$, and so $\frac{1}{\cosh \pi z} = e^{-\pi z} \frac{2}{1+e^{-2\pi z}}$. I know that $e^{-\pi z}$ would satisfy the above inequality, but I cannot deal with the denominator. How could I show this part?

Comment: Note that it is $+$ and the condition on $\Im z$ ensures the denominator is bounded away from zero

Comment: @Conrad My mistake with the sign, but how do we use the condition to ensure that the denominator is bounded away from zero?

Comment: $\Re e^{-2\pi z}=e^{-2\pi x}\cos 2\pi y$ so if $x \ge 0, a>\frac{1}{4}$, $\Re e^{-2\pi z} \ge \cos 2\pi a =\delta(a) > -1$, while for $0 \le a \le \frac{1}{4}$ $\Re e^{-2\pi z} \ge 0$ anyway; for $x <0$ you gotta use the symmetric expression of the hyperbolic cosine (take $e^{\pi z}$ factor etc)

Comment: @Conrad I'm sorry I can't follow your argument. How do we have $\cos 2\pi y \ge \cos 2 \pi a$ for $|y| < a$? And I don't get how having this inequality gives the moderate decrease property. I would greatly appreciate a thorough argument showing $\cosh \pi z$ satisfies the moderate decrease property in $x$ if you have time. I'm new to this subject and quite struggling with showing these bounds.

Comment: done as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \ge 0$. Note that $|e^{-\pi z}|=e^{-\pi x} \le \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ as $(1+x^2)e^{-\pi x}$ is positive decreasing on $[0, \infty)$, so we need to prove only that $|1+e^{-2\pi iz}| \ge C(a) >0$ when $|\Im z| < a <\frac{1}{2}$ as then we can take $A=\frac{2}{C(a)}$.

But $\Re {e^{-2\pi z}}=e^{-2\pi x}\cos 2\pi y$, so if $|a| \le \frac{1}{4}$, $\Re {e^{-2\pi z}} \ge 0$, so $|1+e^{-2\pi iz}| \ge 1$ hence we can take $C(a)=1$. If $\frac{1}{4} <a < \frac{1}{2}$, $\cos 2\pi y \ge \cos 2\pi a=\delta(a) >-1$ since for $|y| \le \frac{1}{4}, \cos 2\pi y \ge 0$, while if $\frac{1}{4} < |y| <a <\frac{1}{2}$, $\cos$ is negative and decreasing for the positive $y$ and obviously $\cos$ is even so the negative $y$ satisfies same inequality. Since $e^{-2\pi x} \le 1$, we get $\Re {e^{-2\pi z}} \ge \delta(a) >-1$, hence $|1+e^{-2\pi iz}| \ge 1+\delta(a) >0$, so we take $C(a)=1+\delta(a)$.

(note that if $0 \le c \le 1, w<0, cw \ge w$, so $e^{-2\pi x}\cos 2\pi y \ge e^{-2\pi x}\cos 2\pi a \ge \cos 2\pi a$, when $\cos 2\pi a <0$)

For $x$ negative one can use that the cosine hyperbolic is even so the inequality is same as for $-x$ (or take $e^{-\pi z}$ factor and repeat)

Comment: I think you miswrote $e^{2\pi i z}$ inside the absolute signs. Also why is the real part of $e^{2\pi z} \ ge \delta(a)$? I would be $\ge e^{2\pi x} \delta(a)$ but as you pointed out $e^{2\pi x} \ le 1$

Comment: fixed first and explained second ($cw \ge w, w<0, 0 \le c \le 1$)